# jQuery UI slide ease sibling push

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slide

I'm using jQuery UI's `slide` toggle effect to toggle a div:

```
$("#link").click(function(){
    $("#targetDiv").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
});
```

Slide is the only effect that has the animation that I want, essentially, the div coming down from the top. I don't want `toggleSlide` because that sort of just changes the height of the element.

The only problem with `slide` is that it immediately pushes siblings around to the end positions: http://jsfiddle.net/XYDyy/2/

So is there some way to have sibling elements adjust their position as the animating div adjusts?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can cheat it by doing a `slideUp()`/`slideDown()` on the `.ui-effects-wrapper` that jQuery adds around the element:

```
$("#link").click(function() {
    if ($("#div1").is(':visible')) {
        $("#div1").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
        $("#div1").parent(".ui-effects-wrapper").slideUp(1000);
    } else {
        $("#div1").toggle("slide", {direction: "up"}, 1000);
        $("#div1").parent(".ui-effects-wrapper").hide().slideDown(1000);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/LARkS/

Otherwise, you could add your own wrapper, and do the `slideUp` on it, with the position of `#div1` set to `bottom: 0px`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/RDWt8/