# Show portion of toggle div, then click on portion to reveal entire div

Tags: jquery

I am using a 'toggle' slide effect and would like to show a portion of the div which the user can click to reveal the entire div.  The problem with the solution I have now is that #click_here jumps left to right when 'toggle' is triggered.  I would like to find a solution where #click_here gradually moves left to right with the slide animation when 'toggle' is triggered.

This my jQuery script so far:

```
$('#click_here').click(function() {
var effect = 'slide';
var options = { direction: 'left' };
var duration = 700;
$('#info_box').toggle(effect, options, duration);
     return false;
});
```

And this my html

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="click_here">
        <p>Click here!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="info_box">
        <h1>Here is some cool info!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
#wrap { background:gray; width:400px; margin:0 auto; height:300px; border:5px blue solid; }

#info_box { width:300px; height:200px; background:pink; float:left; display:inline-block;  overflow:hidden; display:none; }

#click_here { width:100px; height:200px; float:left; background:yellow; display:inline-block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NinoLopezWeb/92Xcm/1/

Thank you!

Comment: Can you switch the divs? this way it slides from under the click here http://jsfiddle.net/enXVM/

Comment: Just saw this very similar question and interesting answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092794/jquery-ui-slide-ease-sibling-push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the way jQuery UI slide toggle works is by inserting a wrapper around the element and animating the element's `left` position. However, the wrapper takes up the full width of the final element, so your "click button" immediately moves to the right. (See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092794/jquery-ui-slide-ease-sibling-push) for a work-around.)

Instead of using that toggle effect, you could use jQuery's [`animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate a CSS margin.

```
#wrap {
    ...
    overflow:hidden;     /* hide overflowing content */
}

#info_box {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:pink;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:-300px;      /* move the element out of sight
}
```

Then use your click handler to animate the `margin-left` back to "0px":

```
$('#click_here').click(function () {
    var duration = 700;
    $('#info_box').animate({
        'margin-left':'0px'
    },duration);
    return false;
});
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/92Xcm/2/)

---

### Edit:

Another method is to use let CSS handle the animation and just use jQuery to toggle a class:

```
#info_box {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:pink;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:-300px;

    -webkit-transition-duration:.7s;
    -moz-transition-duration:.7s;
    -ms-transition-duration:.7s;
    -o-transition-duration:.7s;
    transition-duration:.7s;
}

#info_box.show {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Then just toggle the "show" class with jQuery:

```
$('#click_here').click(function () {
    $('#info_box').toggleClass('show');
    return false;
});
```

Please note the [browser compatibility of CSS transitions](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions).

[WORKING EXAMPLE (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/92Xcm/4/)